# Helping travellers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I suppose it's currently rather off-topic to ask for advice about synagogues and restaurants, when someone travels abroad. There's indeed this *product-recommendation* tag in a similar vein. I think it would be extremely useful to create something similar to take advantage of community members all around the world. Mostly I'm thinking about providing information about:

- rabbi
- nusach (Ashkenaz, Sefarad, Mizrach, Ari etc.)
- available days and prayers (weekdays/holidays, mincha only etc.)
- location, contact if needed

For restaurants:

- style
- hekhsher

Obviously it would be quite "administrator-intensive" to keep it tidy, but other sites on the internet tend to be out-dated.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75827 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66786 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66305

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86593

Comment: @msh210 It seems that others are not really interested... :-(

Comment: @IsaacMoses? Thought it would be better to ask before getting a flood of downvotes...

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that any lists made on this site are just as likely to be incomplete and go out of date as a list on any other website. StackExchange in general has a [policy against this type of question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic). There's no reason we should make an exception when nothing is different.